# Error Running Playframework2 Web Application

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.2

When I run my `playframework2` web application using IntelliJ idea

```
[frontend] $ run 9000
```

I get this error message:

```
Path(C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\frontend\logs\application.log) is not a directory so descendants can not be called on itis not a directory
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 17 avr. 2015 23:22:42
```

Comment: Play thinks C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\frontend\logs\application.log should be a directory. You should correct this path to C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\frontend\logs\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Seems](http://osdir.com/ml/play-framework/2013-07/msg00799.html) to do with incorrectly terminated Java/JVM.

Try seeing if you can find something like a zombie Java instance in the process manager, or alternatively try again after a reboot.